# HOW do i remove quotes from object which contains strings

Tags: javascript

In the below example, I want to remove quotes from key value pairs which is present for sample property.

For example, consider an object

```
var obj={
  sample:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}
}
```

Comment: You can't remove the delimiter quotes.

Comment: What's the purpose of that?

Comment: There are no quotes in the strings?

Comment: when i try to access obj.sample.a , i am getting undefined

Comment: But that's unrelated to your question? In that case how are you actually defining obj. What are you doing with it before you try to access it?

Comment: how can i access property "a"

Comment: this is the actual example,{"fullName":"sanjay hp","id":1,"typeOfUser":"borrower","adhaarNumber":"12345678","createdAt":"2016-02-18T10:56:35.000Z","updatedAt":"2016-04-11T08:58:31.000Z","user_id":1,"profilePic":"/img/avatar.svg"}}

Comment: in the above example i want to access fullname, how i access

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of putting it in comments. Then you can open your question again. Most people wont read through all the comments.

Comment: "i want to access fullname" - maybe there is your problem? The field is called `fullName`, not `fullname`. Capital N.

Answer (score 1):

For the `key` parts, you can omit them as long as they don't have spaces, start with anything other than a letter, etc ie you can use `a:"b"` but not `1a:"b"`or `a a:"b"`. For the `value` part, the quotes represent the limits of the `String` and therefore are needed.

Another option would be that the value **contained** those quotes, which is a different story altogether. Say:

```
a:""b"" //which would be declared as a:"\"b\""
```

In this case we can remove them from the begining and the end of the string, like so:

```
myStringWithDoubleQuotes.replace(/^"(.+(?="$))"$/, '$1');
```

Comment: i want to remove quotes from keys

Comment: keys don't *have* quotes. If you cant access it like `obj.sample.a` you'r problem is somewhere else.